# getting errors while instantiating pointer for structs of native c++ code from c++/cli

Tags: c++, interop, c++-cli, mixed-mode

below mentioned is my c++/cli "*.h" file

```
// rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h
#ifndef RMSCINTERFACE_H
#define RMSCINTERFACE_H
#ifndef RMSREQINFO_H
#define RMSREQINFO_H
#ifndef RMSCLIENTINFO_H
#define RMSCLIENTINFO_H
#ifndef RMSPHYSICIANINFO_H
#define RMSPHYSICIANINFO_H
#ifndef RMSREQPOLICYINFO_H
#define RMSREQPOLICYINFO_H

#pragma once
#include "D:\nbsource code\RMS\rmsCAPI\rmsCInterface.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"rmsCAPI.lib")
#include "D:\nbsource code\RMS\rmsDLL\rmsReqInfo.h"
#include "D:\nbsource code\RMS\rmsDLL\rmsClientInfo.h"
#include "D:\nbsource code\RMS\rmsDLL\rmsPhysicianInfo.h"
#include "D:\nbsource code\RMS\rmsDLL\rmsReqPolicyInfo.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"rmsDLL.lib")

using namespace System;

namespace rmsCInterfaceWrapper
{
public ref class rmsCInterface
{
    // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
private:
    rmsReqInfoStruct *rmsReqInfo;
    rmsClientInfoStruct *rmsClientInfo;
    rmsPhysicianInfoStruct *rmsPhysicianInfo;
    rmsReqPolicyInfoStruct *rmsReqPolInfo;
    rmsAddlOrderInfoStruct *rmsAddOrderInfo;
public:
    rmsCInterface();
    ~rmsCInterface();
    long OrderReq();
};
}
#endif
```

i have declared pointer for these native c++ structures rmsReqInfoStruct, rmsClientInfoStruct, rmsPhysicianInfoStruct, rmsReqPolicyInfoStruct, rmsAddlOrderInfoStruct. wheni compile this i am getting these below mentioned errors and i am not sure why i am getting those

```
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(30) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(30) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(30) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(31) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(31) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(31) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(32) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(32) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(32) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(33) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(33) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(33) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(34) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(34) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\vamsi\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmscinterfacewrapper\rmsCInterfaceWrapper.h(34) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

All these errors are showing up at the structure pointers in the class private declaration itself and i am unable to figure them out why they are causing. can any one please help.

Comment: Multiple guesses: you should forward declare your structs.
Are the given structs lying in the "System" namespace as defined?
Replace the #pragma once with correct guards

Comment: @akaltar--- the structs lies in the header files that i have included but not in the namespace. i removed #pragma and tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Remove defines RMSREQINFO_H, RMSCLIENTINFO_H, etc

Comment: @DarkGray---If i remove them i am getting even more errors (redefinition errors) so when i included them the errors got decreased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. As i have created a clr--->class library project it automatically generated the stdafx.h and stdafx.cpp files. As i am writing  a wrapper around my native c++ code using c++/cli i copied the auto generated c++/cli stdafx.h file with my native stdafx.h file and removed the #ifndef,#define,#pragma statements from the .h file that i have provided above, so doing all these it worked, and i was able to generate the dll file which i can use in my c# program as a reference... Thank you every one for your help...